# increasing size of this data repository in Hadoop-MapReduce cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, bigdata

For a video repository that uses Hadoop-MapReduce cluster and receives around 30000 Terabytes of data every day, how the disk storage requirement can be met in the cluster?
Any help in this case would be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Behrouz

Answer (score 0):

increase the data node storage in the cluster and make replication factor =  0
hope this will suffice your answer

Comment: Dear Pankaj, Thanks for the reply. I do agree with adding nodes, but I think I can't change the replication factor as I need to have copies of the file chunks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do some basic calculations

Every day input size = 30000 TB. 
Replication Factor = 3. 
For running MR or Spark (worst case),  storage factor =1

Hence you need = 30000 *4  TB  of storage on HDFS per day.

Lets assume you delete legacy data every 30 days, which makes HDFS space requirement   30000 *4 *30  TB

Key pointers to keep in mind.

1. Try to have atleast 30% of your HDFS free for MapReduce and spark jobs to run
2. Depending on your video format , use a compression lib to compress the data and save it on HDFS. Uncompressed Data on HDFS is not of much use and results into higer I/O during MR, spark runtime.